# Splitting text in two sections when introducing figure

Tags: pdftex

First of all, thanks for reading.

I am trying to write my first report with latex and I am having a strange error that no one of my friends can solve.  I am writing a two column article. When I try to include a Figure in one of the sections (Introduction) the two or three last lines jump into the next section.
Here you have the full code, and the image of the pdf that I get.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article} %tamaño de papel, letra y clase.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Codificación del documento. utf8 es la más actual.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{bm} %letras griegas en negrita (uso: \bm{\alpha})
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure} %paquete de imágenes y de imágenes dobles
          \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel,color,textcomp,anysize,eurosym,amsthm,multicol,float}
%\usepackage{booktabs} %para poder añadir tablas
%\usepackage{hyperref} %si lo activamos el índice aparecerá con hipervínculos
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %añadir una paleta de 68 colores más a los predefinidos
\usepackage{flushend}%Iguala la altura de las dos columnas de la última pagina
\marginsize{1.5 cm}{1.5cm}{1cm}{1cm} %MÁRGENES: izq,der,sup,inf
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %sangría 
\parskip=4mm %espacio entre párrafos
%\usepackage{lineno} %paquete para numerar las líneas
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf} %esta y la anterior para poner Figure X en negrita
%\pagestyle{empty} %No numerar las páginas. 
\newcommand{\emptyfootnote}{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext} %con     \emptyfootnote{text} podrás poner una nota sin número
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.6cm} %Separacion entre columnas en el modo twocolumn

%opening
\title{\textbf{Improving Generators' Interface to Support
\\LHEF V3 Format}}
\author{\Large ME
\\Universidad, Spain
\\ DESY Summer Student}
\date{September 11, 2014}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[ %Título, autor y abstract centrados y resto del documento en dos columnas
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
  \vspace*{2cm}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}  %Por defecto numera la primera. Con esta orden lo evitamos.
    \vspace*{-0.8cm} %Acerca la línea superior a la fecha
    \begin{center}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.1mm} \end{center} %Añade separación al     abstract y lo separa del resto del documento con una línea horizontal
    \begin{abstract}
    The aim of the project was to modify the Les Houches Event File Interface in order to make it capable of reading the newest version of LHEF format. A partially modified version of the interface was used as an starting point. From there, some features where implemented until the software was fully functional.

    \end{abstract}
    \begin{center}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.1mm} \end{center}
    \vspace*{9cm} %Separa la línea inferior del texto
%  \begin{figure}[t]
%     \begin{center}
%        \includegraphics[width=50pt]{pics/DESY.png}
%        \caption{\small Representation of the trajectories followed by the photoelectrons when they do not have enough energy to reach the collector}
%        \label{cutoff}
%     \end{center}
%\end{figure}
    \begin{center}
        {\includegraphics[height=40pt]{pics/ATLAS.png}}
        \hspace*{3cm}
        {\includegraphics[height=50pt]{pics/DESY.png}}
%        \begin{flushright}
        \hspace*{3cm}
        {\includegraphics[height=55pt]{pics/UGR.png}}
%       \end{flushright}
    \end{center}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
] 

\section*{INTRODUCTION}
This reports is giving a dedicated account of my project in the ATLAS group. The main purpose of the project was to implement new features for what is called Les Houches Event File (LHEF hereafter) interface. This interface is part of Athena, an ATLAS control framework for particle physics Monte Carlo simulation.
In particle physics Monte Carlo simulation we have four basic steps:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Event Generation (Hard Process)
    \item Parton Showers
    \item Hadronization
    \item Underlying Event
\end{itemize}

In the next plot it is shown the steps asociated with each part of the event.

\begin{figure}[h]
     \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=240pt]{pics/Evento.jpg}
        \caption{\small \cite{Webber} MC simulations steps}
        \label{FDplot}
     \end{center}
\end{figure}

In the following sections this framework is going to be explained as well as some formats (HepMC and LHEF) that would be necessary to know for a full understanding of the project. After that, the modified interface will be presented.

\section*{Athena}{

As it is mentioned before, Athena is a control framework that is used to run the particle physics Monte Carlo simulation in ATLAS. The whole process can be done using this framework. 
Athena has six basic steps:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Initialization: The settings and initial values can be introduced to the framework via the JobOptions. This JobOptions are written in Python.
    \item Call the generator via the interface and give it the settings
    \item Read the event data generated.
    \item Castilla y León.
    \item Castilla y León.
    \item Castilla y León.
\end{itemize}
}
\section*{RESULTS \& DISCUSSION}

\section*{CONCLUSIONS}

 \begin{thebibliography}{9}

 \bibitem{Webber}
 B. Webber, \textit{Monte Carlo Methods in Particle Physics}, University of Cambridge, IMPRS, Munich 19-23 November 2007.

  \end{thebibliography}         
\end{document}
```

And I get:
[image: Error]

As you can see in the code, the red rectagle of text should be in the Introduction, not in Athena.

Thank you very much,
Fernando

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I compiled with the `demo` option for `graphicx`, and `subfigure`loading removed (it's not installed on my system), and I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: i can't say that it really makes a difference, but the braces around the `\section*{Athena}{ ... }` look fishy to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the inclusion of the package `flushend` is to blame for the problem behavior you're encountering.

As I understand it, the purpose of this package is to balance the columns if a page is not completely full. However, there must be one or more bugs in that package, the results of which are the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

For now, I would NOT load that `flushend` package.

Comment: It seems that this can be the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

As a provisional solution if the image is 220p instead of 240p, everything works.

Fernando

Comment: Please see the answer that I just posted.